# Hewlett Packard update breaks CDatabase::IsFieldNull( )

Tags: windows, mfc, odbc

I have a grueling problem with a Hewlett Packard update on a Windows 7 machine. At least, 7 is the only place I've seen it. This happened about a half a year ago, the guy didn't need to use that machine so I got out of trying to fix it at the time. What happens:

HP does an update on the machine and breaks the database interface as far as `null` fields go. Concerning `CDatabase`, after the update a call to `IsFieldNull( )` will always return **false** even if the field is tagged `null`. The likes of `AfxFieldText(...)` use this flag to set the text field empty otherwise it will fetch a: 1246576928 into the field. I can't cheat, make `IsFieldNull( )` virtual in the VC headers, the linker doesn't agree and I certainly didn’t want to hack the MFC dlls.

Yes, I've searched on this, nothing. I went around with HP last time. Of course if I'm the only one complaining, they have no interest. Now this client's problem in mine, I can't tell them to reinstall Windows or get another computer. I'm presently looking at a major hack, I have 68 uses of `IsFieldNull( )` much less the dependency of `CDatabase` and all the rest. And doing that in a separate build for them as I don't want to hack our core product.

I'm just wondering if anyone has an idea better than what I'm looking forward to.

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking, and I sure didn't want to go through that hack...

There was this issue back in 2011 when I first moved to vs100. It took sp1 on Visual Studio to fix it. So somewhere HP must have used the older dlls and patch them into this computer. I did update the SYSTEM32 dlls, but now I'm wondering if that WOW64 folder is where the culprit lived.

So I had been resisting compiling all my dlls and main product with vs140. Turns out it was not that painful, got it done in a day. I just dropped a folder on the users computer with the new stuff and tested from there.

That fixed it. So if anyone is still using vs10 and is shipping product, and using `CDatabase`, this could bite you on an HP update. I've seen it three times in the last year. Once with a printer driver installation. And twice with an HP update.